# C#/.NET inheritance best practice

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am wondering what the best practice is on a database schema for inheriting from a base class where the base class has the PK id.

Let's say I'm building an app for a school. There are Teachers and Staff each with their own "duties". I want an Employee base class. Then, I want ONE Duty class that can be for any type of employee. Meaning, I don't want to create a TeacherDuty class with a FK to the TeacherId and a second StaffDuty class with a FK to StaffId, I'd like one Duty class, bound to the EmployeeId.

What is best practice here? Or is it best practice to have a TeacherDuty and StaffDuty class with FK's to each of their respective classes. I'm trying to minimize the number of classes and make them as reusable as possible (for instance, if there's another type of Employee, like Administrator, I want to avoid creating yet another table for AdministratorDuty).

```
public class Employee
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
}

public class Teacher: Employee 
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
}

public class Teacher: Employee
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
}

public class Duty 
{
  //what's the FK here?
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `TeacherId` and `StaffId`? Shouldn't `Id` be enough? If there isn't a good reason, the FK can be `Id`.

Comment: First off. Think of how to normalize this. A Teacher is an Employee. But in your example it is also Staff. That will not work. Further when a Teacher inherits Employee it also inhertits its Id. So a second TeacherId is nonsense. Make an image of your model before you dive into code.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I typed that wrong.

Comment: Your new edit doesn't make a lot of sense. There's no `Staff`, nor `TeacherId` and `StaffId`. Are you able to edit the question so that the code matches the question or vice versa.

Comment: As mentioned earlier. Don't dive into code just yet. First try and think your model through. Make a drawing on paper or whatever and define the entities you want and their dependencies. Try and focus on the problem before you start coding.

Comment: _I'm trying to minimize the number of classes_ Why? It makes it complicated to adjust later. Have you considered using namespaces and schemas to keep your code and database organised?

Answer (score 1):

Your hierarchy still doesn't quite make sense because you have a Teacher class there twice identically. I assume one of them is meant to be `Staff` instead of `Teacher`. But even with that, I'm not quite sure why Teacher would not be considered staff also?

It's important to properly designing your schema before continuing. I'll attempt to answer you actual question, but that doesn't mean this is necessarily the correct way to go about it. I've proposed an alternative schema design at the end for you to consider.

## Answering your Question

To answer your question, we can look at how ORM's (Namely Entity Framework Core) solve this kind of thing. The issue is, the concept of OOP and classes doesn't fully map over to the Relational database world. C# ORM's like Entity Framework have to do this so even if you're not going to use Entity Framework, looking at how they solve this issue can give you insight.

To make it more obvious what is going on, I'm going to add some fake columns to each your classes. Let's pretend this is what your C# classes look like:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } 
}

public class Administrator : Employee
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Employee
{
    public string HomeRoom { get; set; }
}
```

So you can see both Administrators and teachers should share an Id and whether they are active or not. Administrators store their phone number, and teachers need a home room. Administrators do not need a home room and teachers do not need a phone number. Again, the columns aren't meant to be a real use case, just as an example.

**Table per Hierarchy**

The first way (and recommended/default way in Entity Framework Core) is to do a [single table per Hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration). This means you would have a table called `Employee`, and that table would have all the columns required to represent every type of employee (Staff, Teacher, Administrator, etc). This means there would be 1 `EmployeeID` column to represent all employees. The magic comes from having a 'Discriminator' column to  specify 'This employee is a X'.

So your `Employee` table would look something like this:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | NVARCHAR(50) PK |
| Discriminator | NVARCHAR(100) (NOT NULL) |
| IsActive | BIT (NOT NULL) |
| PhoneNumber | NVARCHAR(50) (NULLABLE) |
| HomeRoom | NVARCHAR(50) (NULLABLE) |

And the data might look something like this:

| Id | Discriminator | IsActive | PhoneNumber | HomeRoom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Teacher | 1 | NULL | 2A |
| 2 | Administrator | 1 | 3256-6986 | NULL |

In this situation your duty table would have a FK of `EmployeeID`, which would join to this table. Conceptually it's simple, but you have to make sure you always add the discriminator when doing queries for a specific type. Using EF Core, this is mostly handled for you.

If you wanted to query out all the Teachers, you'd do a query something like this:

`SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Discriminator = 'Teacher'`

The reason this is the default way in EF Core is because it allows for faster querying of data. Everything about this 1 type is stored in the one table. That benefit is also one of its weaknesses. You can see that a `Teacher` row has to store that it's `PhoneNumber` is null, even though that data is not relevant to a teacher. This is okay in this small sample, but if you have a bunch of employee types that each have a lot of unique columns, you add a lot of bloat to your table. This can make it hard to understand what it going on.

**Table-per-type**

The second way to do it is by doing a [table per type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration). In this way, you'd have an Employee table with just Id and IsActive. Then there'd be a separate table for Teacher/Administator which holds the specific data for those classes.

The schema's might look something like this:

`Employee`
| Column | Type |
|---- |-------|
| Id | NVARCHAR(50) PK Identity |
| IsActive | BIT (NOT NULL) |

`Administrator`
| Column | Type |
|---- |-------|
| EmployeeId | NVARCHAR(50) PK |
| PhoneNumber | NVARCHAR(50) (NULLABLE) |

`Teacher`
| Column | Type |
|---- |-------|
| EmployeeId | NVARCHAR(50) PK |
| HomeRoom | NVARCHAR(50) (NULLABLE) |

It's a bit harder to show what the data would look like, but essentially you'd have every employee inside the employee table. Then if they were a teacher, there would be a record in the Teacher table with a matching EmployeeId.

So if you wanted to query out all the teachers with this method, you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Teacher ON Teacher.EmployeeId = Employee.Id
```

The benefit to this way is that you aren't storing any wasted data.

The downside is that you could potentially make your queries a lot more complex by adding in a lot of joins. [In the EF Core docs they mention this performance hit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/modeling-for-performance#inheritance-mapping).

## Alternative

I mentioned at the start that I would try to answer your question as is, which I have done. But I also think it's important to offer alternatives that may or may not apply. To me it seems like you're starting with an OOP approach to how you want your data to look, and then you're asking 'How can I map this to a database'. An OOP design doesn't really work 100% with schema's though, so instead start with a schema, then figure out how to represent that with classes.

Consider the following: Is it ever possible for an employee to have multiple roles? With your current system, someone is locked into being 1 type of employee. What if someone changes roles? Maybe they started as an Administrator but changed to a teacher? I'm not saying this is definitely an issue. Maybe you'd consider someone changing jobs a new employee, in which case your current way would work.

I'd propose structuring it completely differently though. Have your `Employee` table contain all the information all employees could need (no matter what role they have). Then have a separate table called something like `Role`, which has a row for all the different types of employees possible. For example it'd have a row for 'Teacher', 'Administrator', 'Grounds Keeper', etc. This way adding new roles is as easy as adding a row into a table.

Then you'd have a many-many table called `EmployeeRole`, which just stores an `EmployeeID` and `RoleID` (And maybe an `IsActive` to say if they are still in that role). That way a single employee can have multiple roles, and you'd have a history of their previous roles they've had before.

Then you could have your `Duty` table have a FK to this `EmployeeRole` table, instead of directly to the Employee table. Each Role the employee has would then have a different set of Duty's.

I'm not a Database designer though and this design is definitely not without its own flaws, so think about your use case and carefully design what limitations you need to allow for. Don't think about your code in OOP terms, create a class structure from your schema. Use my example as a way to think differently about the problem, but don't just follow what I proposed blindly.

## Summing up

If you want to stick with your original design, I think Table-Per-Hierarchy works best for you. But I strongly recommend re-thinking your schema and figuring out what kind of limitations apply to it, and whether you need to allow for those.